# Calculate difference of dates belonging to same group in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, duplicates

I have following set of data:

```
ClassName | Dates     | ClassID
----------------
ClassA    | 21-Jun-16 | 1238
ClassA    | 27-Jun-16 | 1238
ClassB    | 14-Apr-11 | 1252
ClassB    | 14-Apr-11 | 1252
ClassC    | 26-Oct-15 | 1261
ClassC    | 21-Oct-15 | 1261
```

For each group of ClassName or ClassID I want to take difference of dates.

The output should have the following format-

```
ClassName | Days     | ClassID
----------------
ClassA    | 5 | 1238
ClassB    | 0 | 1252
ClassC    | 4 | 1261
```

Please suggest!
Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using. Also will it be always two entries per `Class`

Comment: Yes, it will always be two entries per class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, you can do something like this:

```
select ClassName, ClassId,
       max(date) - min(date) as days
from t
group by ClassName, ClassId;
```

However, the logic for subtracting dates might differ among databases.